# How to change cursor dynamically while dragging in IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cursor, mouse

With the following JS code, I am trying to replace the cursor while dragging. It works well for Chrome and FF ,not IE. Any workaround?

```
$("body").mousedown(function() {
  $("body").mousemove(function(){
    $("body").addClass("dragging");
  });
});
$("body").mouseup(function() {
    $("body").unbind('mousemove');
    $("body").removeClass("dragging");
});


.dragging {
    cursor: no-drop;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of a workaround for this, as [this article](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/cursor/) from CSS-Tricks makes clear:

"The following not supported in IE or Opera: not-allowed, no-drop, vertical-text, all-scroll, col-resize, row-resize"

Sorry I can't provide a workaround, but hopefully the article clears up any confusion.

Comment: Hi, it doesn't matter whether no-drop is supported or not by IE. I can use any image here if no-drop is not supported. The key is that IE doesn't allow changing the cursor once Dragging is started. I just wan t to confirm whether this is a limitation of IE?